# ASP.NET Core API Testing - What should/shouldn't we test with TestServer?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, asp.net-core, integration-testing

Now that we have [TestServer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/testing/integration-testing) to perform integration tests for our ASP.NET Core applications, i'm trying to figure out what we *should* and *shouldn't* be testing when building API's.

Pre-ASP.NET Core, i would generally have 2x test projects for my API:

1. `MyApi.UnitTests` => testing controller, services, utilities etc. Testing one thing, everything else mocked.
2. `MyApi.IntegrationTests` => testing database, external API's etc. Hits the real db/service.

Now, obviously we still need `UnitTests`. But my question is, what should we be testing with *TestServer* integration tests, exactly?

My initial thought was I test each API endpoint with TestServer, like this:

```
[Fact]
public async Task DoingAGetRequestToPeople_ShouldReturnPeopleAsJson()
{
    // Arrange.
    var client = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder()
                                         .UseStartup<Startup>()).CreateClient();

    // Act.
    var response = await client.GetAsync("/api/people");

    // Assert.
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Assert.NotNull(responseString);
    var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<People>>(responseString);
    Assert.NotNull(model);
}
```

But, since it's a full E2E integration test, will *also* hit the DB and hence be testing that too. Is that testing *too much*? Do we then need *separate* tests *just* testing the DB calls? (e.g "unit" tests, that actually hit the DB?)

Hopefully that makes sense. Basically i'm looking for answers to the following questions:

1. *What is the scope* of what we should/shouldn't be testing with TestServer.
2. *How many test projects* should we generally have for an API project? What are their responsibilities?

Thankyou!

Comment: You could always create a startup specific to the integration tests so that you can mock out the calls to the database. This while still an integration test would help isolate the controller actions and dependencies so that you can still test the endpoints, which would still represent an E2E test.

Comment: @RPM1984 Can you please review the answer and see if it helps or not ? so other can use this answer or add new useful answers

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand why testing perspective/approach should change with Asp.Net Core, compared to what it was before that. I must be missing some aspect.

Anyway, to your questions:

> what should we be testing with TestServer integration tests, exactly?
>
> What is the scope of what we should/shouldn't be testing with TestServer.

My take on those two is:

test the whole API stack, from HTTP(S) endpoint down to a *dedicated* DB server (or DB at least), hence traversing all your layers and especially cross cutting concerns (validation, authentication, ...). Dedicated as in *for testing purposes only*, not a development one (when tests run on a dev machine), nor the production one (when tests run on a CI environment or similar).

Maybe the test DB can be not exactly the same edition as the production one, as in using MS SQL Express instead of full MS SQL Standard/Enterprise, but still you are hitting a real DB at least (and e.g. not an in-memory one) so that connection strings, views, particular queries have to work right.

> How many test projects should we generally have for an API project?

I guess it depends on the granularity you have in your projects under test. If you're on a multi-layered solution, where app server is split among several projects, you could have one unit test project for each of them, plus one single integration test.

Sticking with your starting point, I'd say that you can keep on having two test projects: one for unit tests, one for integration tests.

But then again, you might also have a further test project for some load testing. And maybe more.

> What are their responsibilities?

They basically remains the same as for your pre-Asp.Net Core scenarios. Unit tests still have the same responsibilities. Integration tests have those responsibilities highlighted above.

HTH

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer - it's a great one (+1). Nothing has changed regarding testing practices due to .NET Core, but i guess im just confused as to what tests to write now. Previously, we never wrote full end-to-end tests in the project (that was the job of automated tests _outside_ the project). Now, sounds like that job can be done with Test Server.. but we still have the unit tests for each project/layer. Sound right?

Comment: That sounds right to me.  
I like the idea of E2E tests outside the SUT project altogether, but then those hit actual *external* services/platforms (DB, email, SMS). So I guess you should be able to configure your E2E test environment so your application points to a test version of those services.  
By having integration tests accessing source code, you might tweak your external dependencies a little further, or alter your `Startup` if needed (see e.g. [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49244283/set-dummy-ip-address-in-integration-test-with-asp-net-core-testserver/)).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**Unit tests:** Unit tests should be part of your build server, if one of the unit tests break, all the build should break.

- What is the scope of what we should/shouldn't be testing with TestServer?

Basically, your UI-Tests, Integration tests and E2E project and these shouldn't be part of your solution(maybe even in the different repo) as you can use any technology or any tool to implement that, It is not coupled with your project.

- How many test projects should we generally have for an API project? What are their responsibilities?

The number of projects that make you feel confident with your changes and with your new build release, There is no golden rule for that. But I'm working on a project and I add Unit-tests for my API project and Integration tests to test end-points and in my case, this is enough.

Hope that I ask your question

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but i haven't accepted yet because i'm hoping for some other/more extended answers. Regarding yours,  I have some questions. 1) You mentioned TestServer should be testing UI/Integration/E2e, and shouldn't be part of solution/repo, but.. TestServer needs a reference to the `Startup` class for the project? (see code sample in question). I understand you're have UI tests seperate (e.g hitting a real server on the 'internet'), but i would have thought the integration/e2e tests would be inside. 2) Do you have a reference link for that image? Thanks!